# Check wrong input and stuck in infinite loop (C)

Tags: c

I cannot use string or char input. If I use input like "c" then

```
int x,y,z;
while (1)
{
    z=scanf("%d%d", &x,&y);
    if(z == 0){
        printf("correct!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Incorrect!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct return value for `scanf` should be `2`, not `0`, because you are reading two arguments. If you enter `"c"`, then `scanf` will probably return `0`.

Comment: You are in an infinite loop because you have `while(1)` with no exit condition. And if you enter `c`, it doesn't match the `scanf` format string, so the `c` will not be consumed, so `scanf` will continue to fail until you flush stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check properly against success, not 0.

On failure, consume characters until end-of line.  If `scanf("%c", ...)` or the like not allowed due to "I cannot use string or char input.", you are out of luck.

Exit the loop on success or end-of-file

```
do {
  z = scanf("%d%d", &x,&y);
  //if(z == 0){
  if (z == 2) {
    printf("correct!\n");`
  } else if (z != EOF) {
    printf("Incorrect!\n");
    char ch;
    while ( scanf("%c", &ch) == 1 && ch != '\n') {
      ;
    }
  }
} while (z != 2 && z != EOF);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what exactly you are looking for. I also don't know exactly what this code does, but if you want to stop the infinite loop, hope this helps.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main () {
   int x,y,z;
    while (1) {
        z = scanf("%d%d", &x,&y);
        if(z == 0) {
            printf("correct!\n");
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Incorrect!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: scanf returns the number of variables it captured. So '= 0' cant be correct

Comment: ok, thank you for point that out.